# Checking for multiple arrays if they are empty or their count == 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have been searching for an answer, but have not been able to find any similar questions. So, what I am trying to do is: execute this code function only where the array is either `empty` or the `count == 0`.

I have tried:  `if (DriverOffers.count == 0 && DriverData.count == 0)`, `DriverOffers.isEmpty && DriverData.isEmpty` and replacing `&&` with or `||` just to make sure that this was not the problem.

Here is my code, it is a tableView background view that will appear only if both arrays are empty. The problem is that it does not work for both arrays.

My code:

```
func emptyTableView(){
        
        if (DriverOffers.count == 0 && DriverData.count == 0) {
            
            self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()

            emptyView.isHidden = false
            view.addSubview(emptyView)
            emptyView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245, a: 1)
            emptyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            emptyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            emptyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            emptyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

            emptyView.addSubview(emptyImg)
            emptyView.addSubview(emptyLbl)
            emptyView.addSubview(emptyLbl2)

            DriverOrdersTV.backgroundView = emptyView
            DriverOrdersTV.separatorStyle = .none

            emptyImg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            emptyImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            emptyImg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            emptyImg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

            emptyLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyImg.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            emptyLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

            emptyLbl2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
            emptyLbl2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emptyView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        }
        else {
            DriverOrdersTV.backgroundView = nil

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which is it you want AND (&&) or OR (||)? And why are you mentioning 4 properties in the text but are only checking 2 in the code?

Answer (score 0):

remove this `self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()` or place it after the if statement.
if your function is getting triggered by the tableview Delegate this reloading data will cause you this issue